# Create A responsive Pear Shape using CSS or responsive Images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For a project I have to create a pear-shaped container. I tried doing this using CSS3 rounded corners but it just doesnt look exactly like it. I then used an image at the bottom, but I need this to be responsive (scalable image).

I want to code something like: 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=98fxid&s=5

But as you minimize the browser screen, the layout breaks and the pear shape is not scalable. I would like to know if there is a way to do this using CSS3 OR a better way to do this using scalable images.

By the way, I'm using bootstrap and this is my first attempt at making a website using bootstrap, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking you could use an SVG background image for the entire curved area (instead of just the tip, like your attempt shows) with a background width of 100% (or one of the background cover options). Since it's a vector graphic, it would scale smoothly and the file size would be small.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the pear shape using two intersecting circle segments, one for left-hand side and one for the right-hand side. Circle segments are created by limiting the circle to its parent container via `overflow: hidden;`. To simplify the markup, you can create the child circle elements using the `:before` and/or `:after` pseudo elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-form">
    <div class="pear-shape left"></div>
    <div class="pear-shape right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-form {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 325px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(http://www.domainandseo.com/bootstrap/img/design.png);
    position: relative;
}
.pear-shape {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
}
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
.pear-shape.left:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 250px;
    background: url(http://www.domainandseo.com/bootstrap/img/design.png);
}
.pear-shape.right:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 250px 0;
    background: url(http://www.domainandseo.com/bootstrap/img/design.png);
}
```

Check out this example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrBnF/).

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you will be able to use the css shapes module, and there might be some browsers that already support it. In the mean time, you might want to look at SVG or canvas as an option.

Comment: This is a pretty weak answer.  Do you have an example of how to do this with either of the options you mention?

Comment: with the css shapes module as it isn't completely defined at the moment, it would probably have to be done using two divs and shape-outside (see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/ for an example). For SVG, you would create an SVG image in illustrator or some other vector program, and use it. the trick is mostly in the layout of the content. With css shapes module that is taken care of for the most part.